# ArrayList is empty even after adding values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, google-api, google-places-api

I am developing an app that shows the user different establishments in their area, and to do this I am using the google places API. I am storing all the results in an ArrayList, but for some reason the code to add them to the ArrayList is not running. Any idea what might be the cause? For reference, the relevant part of my code is below:

```
private void handleAutoCompleteRequest(FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request) {
    // Create a new Places client instance.
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

    placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
        for (AutocompletePrediction prediction : response.getAutocompletePredictions()) {

            Log.d("PLACEID", prediction.getPlaceId());
            Log.d("PLACENAME", prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString());

            placeID = prediction.getPlaceId();
            placeName = prediction.getPrimaryText(null).toString();


            // Define a Place ID.
            final String placeId = placeID;

            // Specify the fields to return.
            final List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.BUSINESS_STATUS, Place.Field.RATING, Place.Field.PHOTO_METADATAS);

            // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
            final FetchPlaceRequest request1 = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

            placesClient.fetchPlace(request1).addOnSuccessListener((response1) -> {

                Place place = response1.getPlace();

                Log.d("name", "Place found: " + place.getName());
                Log.d("address", "Place found: " + place.getAddress());
                Log.d("hours", "Place found: " + place.getBusinessStatus());

                String statusString = String.valueOf(place.getBusinessStatus());
                String ratingString = String.valueOf(place.getRating());


                Log.d("placeStatus",statusString);
                Log.d("placeRating",ratingString);

                //PHOTOS///////////////////////////////////////////

                // Get the photo metadata.
                final List<PhotoMetadata> metadata = place.getPhotoMetadatas();
                if (metadata == null || metadata.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.w("metadataNull", "No photo metadata.");
                    return;
                }
                final PhotoMetadata photoMetadata = metadata.get(0);

                // Get the attribution text.
                final String attributions = photoMetadata.getAttributions();

                // Create a FetchPhotoRequest.
                final FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(photoMetadata)
                        .setMaxWidth(500) // Optional.
                        .setMaxHeight(300) // Optional.
                        .build();

                placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {
                    placePhoto = fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap();


                    Log.d("isthisrunning","yesitsrunning");


                    TenderSuggestion mySuggestion = new TenderSuggestion(place.getAddress(), place.getName(), place.getId(), statusString, ratingString, placePhoto);
                    TenderSuggestions.add(mySuggestion);
                    Log.d("testArrayList", "added");


                    for (int i = 0; i < TenderSuggestions.size(); i++) {
                        String master = TenderSuggestions.get(i).getSuggestionName();

                        for (int p = 0; p < TenderSuggestions.size(); p++) {
                            if (p != i) {
                                String subject = TenderSuggestions.get(p).getSuggestionName();
                                if (master.equals(subject)) {
                                    TenderSuggestions.remove(p);
                                    i--;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    NUM_PAGES = TenderSuggestions.size();

                    Log.d("Arraylength1",String.valueOf(TenderSuggestions.size()));

                }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        final ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        Log.e("placeError", "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
                        final int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        // TODO: Handle error with given status code.
                    }
                });


            }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {

                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {

                    final ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;

                    Log.d("error", "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());

                    final int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                    // TODO: Handle error with given status code.
                }
                Log.d("error", "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());

            });

        }

    }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
            Log.d("ERROR", "Place not found: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
        }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: until which point runs your program?  Whats the last statement that gets executed?

Comment: @CodeIsLaw I'm not sure what the last statement to be executed is, but I can say with certainty that `Log.d("isthisrunning","yesitsrunning");`  and everything under it up until `Log.d("Arraylength1",String.valueOf(TenderSuggestions.size()));` does not run. Any idea why this might be happening?